# Chart.js - Responsiveness not correctly working on device orientation change

Tags: javascript, mobile, orientation, chart.js

I have implemented `Chart.js` into my project which works without problems, but I am experiencing **problems while changing the orientation** on a mobile device.
If the screen changes from `portait` mode to `landscape` everything is resized as expected,
**but** when changing form `landscape` to `portrait` **the chart is not being resized**... it keeps the width of the landscape-mode.

I am searching for a way to do this **without** using `jQuery-mobile`

If someone knows how to handle this (wrong) behavior I would be really pleased to know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the orientation change event (in jQuery mobile - [`$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){  ... });`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)) and trigger a window resize (if you have jQuery this could be as simple as `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Alternatively, you could replicate the code that executes when the window is resized in the orientation change handler

```
function () {
    // Basic debounce of resize function so it doesn't hurt performance when resizing browser.
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
                // If the responsive flag is set in the chart instance config
                // Cascade the resize event down to the chart.
                if (instance.options.responsive) {
                    instance.resize(instance.render, true);
                }
            });
        }, 50);
    };
};
```

Which is mostly a copy paste of the Chart.js library code, except that I replaced each with `Chart.helpers.each`

Comment: THX, very much... today I finally found time to test your snipped, it works awesome (this is perfect because I wanted to avoid using jquery mobile)

Comment: Problem solved by css: `canvas {  width: 100% !important; }` with chart options:     `options: { resposive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with mobile gadgets in the different orientation. It was solved using CSS styles. Eg.:

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
 .chart-container {
   min-height: 40vh;
 }
}

@media (orientation:landscape) {
 .chart-container {
   min-height: 90vh;
 }
}
```